# Log4Net - Set conversionPattern for Level Type

Tags: c#, log4net

I am trying to set up Log4Net in my C# WinForms App.config and would like to set different conversionPattern for Debug/Fatal/Info etc.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do one conversion pattern per appender. However Appenders can have level filters. You could create a different appender for each conversion pattern and then apply the appropriate filter. For example:

```
<appender>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
    <levelToMatch value="ERROR"/>
  </filter>
</appender>
```

This [log4net Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial) has all the details.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure its not possible to assign a different conversion pattern on an appender per log level.

You could create multiple appenders with differing thresholds and setup different conversion patterns per appender.  This still wont get you 100% of what you're after however.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pattern layout converter
https://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/creating-your-own-pattern-layout-converter-for-log4net/

In the convert function you get the log level and then you can provide pattern depends on the level.